# Check Used Ports on Linux without Command

Tags: linux, netstat, lsof

Is there a way to check Used Ports on Linux without commands, I mean checking files or so on ?

Comment: What is your goal here? Why aren't you able to use standard tools to do this? The below answer is correct, you can look in /proc, but even for that, you'll need to run *some* command, even if its cat or ls.

Comment: I meant to get used ports without traditional commands like netstat and lsof and so on .. why ? Because I am preparing Script to do this job on different Linux distributions and MAC .. as you know some Linux distributions don't have netstat or lsof , same on MAC .. and Business doesn't want to Bundle netstat with the original application package, the below answer is correct for Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this information in /proc/net/tcp , /proc/net/udp or /proc/net/raw.

More details and syntax here:
http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html

Depending of what you want to do with port numbers, you may have to translate the port number in decimal, as it's stored in hexadecimal in these files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. This is very true on Linux .. Do you know how to do this on MAC ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do this on MacOS.

Comment: dead link; here is an archive [mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20150213042359/http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html)